# ngModelController set model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like

```
require: '^ngModel',
link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    var clear = angular.element('<span style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; height: 14px; margin: auto; right: 20px; cursor: pointer; color: #999;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
    clear.on('click', function () {
        ctrl <- set model to ''
        elem.focus();
        elem.val('');
    });
    elem.after(clear);
}
```

I want to add a clear button to an input field and on clicking this button the input should get empty. But I also want to clear the model of this input. so I want something like `ctrl.$setModel('')`.

I tried:

```
ctrl.$setViewValue('')
ctrl.$modelValue = ''
```

both with no effect. How can I set the model from a directive?

Comment: have you tried require: require: '?ngModel',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call $apply:

```
clear.on('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$setViewValue('')
        ctrl.$render();
    });

    elem.focus();
});
```